# Band pass filter with CSB 455kHz resonator

Tags: filter

I have a 2-pin CSB (ceramic) 455kHz resonator.
I'd like to know how I can make a bandpass 455kHz filter using it.
Can someone please post a schematic?

Comment: What does the data sheet for the device tell you?

Comment: Well, the symbol is ZTB 455E and in the datasheet there is nothing mentioned about applications of this thing.

Comment: It'd help if you provided more data: **bandpass frequency span** and the **stop-band attenuation floor** you're aiming for. The data sheet provides only one-of-four equivalent internal components (Rm, Cm, Lm, Cp). Rm= 20 ohms. You can measure Cp fairly easily with a multimeter that provides "capacitance" function. Lm & Cm require more effort to measure. You need all four for proper filter design.

Answer (score 1):

The data sheet shows how to connect it to an inverter to form an oscillator so, disregard the inverter and, using the two capacitors they specify, you can drive an analogue signal at one end and expect to see a band limited (band pass) output at the other end. You might want to experiment with loading it with maybe 100 ohms at the output end too. It's probably a good idea not to feed signals into it much more than 5 Vp-p or you might damage it.

Comment: This circuit arrangement **DOES give the desired bandpass response**, but provides an unsatisfying stopband attenuation (compared with a crystal). This resonator's internal shunt capacitance is very large. Even cascaded resonators in a "lower-sideband ladder filter" topology suffers this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Use your favorite web search engine to search images of "ceramic filter superheterodyne receiver schematic". There are plenty of examples.